# Div doesn't appear when at the bottom of a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, panel

I have a question about javascript. I'm creating a panel which when scrolling, the panel closes and when we are at the bottom of the page the `#toTop` div will appear.

I have made the function code as below. But when we're at the bottom of a page, the `#toTop` div doesn't appear yet.

**Function for show `#toTop` div if we reach bottom page**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
        openMenu();
  } else if ($("body").height() <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())){
        $("#toTop").css("display","block");
  } else{
        closeMenu();
        $("#toTop").css("display","none");
  }
 });
});
```

is there something missing, or wrong in my code? Please help me. This is [My Codepen](https://codepen.io/fikryrmdhna/pen/xxVLzaR)

**Panel HTML**

```
<div id="floatingPanel">
   <div class="panel-socmed open">
      <a href="#" class="instagram">
         <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="facebook">
         <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="twitter">
         <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="youtube">
         <i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="linkedin">
         <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
      </a>
   </div>
   <div id="closeShare">
       <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
       <i class="fas fa-share-alt"></i>
   </div>
  <div id="toTop">
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Function Open/Close Panel**

```
function toggleMenu() {
   if ($(".panel-socmed").hasClass("open")) {
       openMenu();
   } else {
       closeMenu();
  }
}

function openMenu() {
  $(".panel-socmed").removeClass("open");
  $("#closeShare").find(".fa-times").hide();
  $("#closeShare").find(".fa-share-alt").show();
}

function closeMenu() {
  $(".panel-socmed").addClass("open");
  $("#closeShare").find(".fa-times").show();
  $("#closeShare").find(".fa-share-alt").hide();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#closeShare').click(function() {
      toggleMenu();
});
```

Comment: i think $(this).scrollTop() > 0 should be $(this).scrollTop() <= 0

Comment: ```$(this).scrollTop() > 0``` open panel, not ```#toTop```. Logic for show ```#toTop``` when at the bottom of page is this => ```$("body").height() <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())``` @firatozcevahir

Comment: Yes but when user scrolls down it will always hit the first case of the if statement, because `$(this).scrollTop()` will be always bigger than 0

Comment: i tried to make an if under if, it worked. like this. How's simple the code? => ```if ($("body").height() <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())){
       $("#toTop").css("display","block");
     } else {
       $("#toTop").css("display","none");
     }
   });```

Comment: You want `Totop` div to hide when at the end of the page - thats all ?

Comment: not closed but show only when at the bottom of the page @AlwaysHelping

Comment: I have deleting my working answer as it was exactly you wanted - since i cannot help further considering its very unclear what you wants here to actually to what you are saying in comments

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to display `#toTop` and close the panel only when you scroll to the bottom, a minor change in you scroll function will fix it.

```
  $(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
        openMenu();
  }  if ($("body").height() <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())){
        $("#toTop").css("display","block");
  } else{
        closeMenu();
        $("#toTop").css("display","none");
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: when scroll bottom, just panel is closed. but when it is at the bottom of the page, ```#toTop``` appears. @RitSar

Comment: Just noticed Piyush did the same but it was edited, is this not what you require?

Answer (score 0):

Below script should do what you need:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
          openMenu();
       } else{
          closeMenu();
       }
    
     if ($("body").height() <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())){
       $("#toTop").css("display","block");
     } else {
       $("#toTop").css("display","none");
     }
   });
```

As @firatozcevahir also mentioned, `$(this).scrollTop() > 0` it would evaluate to true so next else part would never be executed.

Comment: it doesnt work. i tried with this code, and it work. an if below if ```if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
          openMenu();
         $("#toTop").css("display","block");
       } else{
          closeMenu();
         $("#toTop").css("display","none");
       }```. and this is the code =>  ```if ($("body").height() <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())){
       $("#toTop").css("display","block");
     } else {
       $("#toTop").css("display","none");
     }
   });```

Comment: Great, was not sure about what you exactly wanted